# My npm is not working

Tags: node.js, http, npm

my npm is not working at all. Not only when I'm trying to install using a package.json file, but also when I'm just trying to install a node module.  Here is what comes up in the terminal:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express/3.3.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express-hbs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ember
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongojs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/everyauth
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/path
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/charlotte
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io-client

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: mongojs
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/christian/nave/myspendingNode/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/christian/nave/myspendingNode
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: mongojs
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/christian/nave/myspendingNode/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Can anyone point me in the direction to fix this?

Comment: Is your registry set to the right address? `Error: failed to fetch from registry: mongojs` Or have you checked if you're behind a proxy?

Comment: I'm not behind a proxy and how would I change the address in npm?

Comment: @NimaVaziri post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

This basically changes the url to `http` instead of the default `https`